# Android: Videoview lose the pause state after change orientation

Tags: android, rotation, android-videoview

i'm playing audio with Videoview. If try to change orientation during the player in pause state, the player loses this state and continues to play.

I have try to stop it but not succeeded.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("pos", mediaView.getCurrentPosition());
    outState.putBoolean("playerState", mediaView.isPlaying());
}
```

and on restore

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    boolean playerState = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("playerState");
    if(playerState) {
        mediaView.start();
    } else {
        this.posOfMedia = mediaView.getCurrentPosition();

        mediaView.pause();
    }
}
```

has anybody an idea how can I keep pause state after rotation